# Laravel/Lumen Model query with:: and where: How to do this right?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen, laravel-5.5

Hey there in Laravel/Lumen I have got a Model "Article". The following works:

```
    $article = Article::with('ArticleTranslations',
       'ArticleTranslations.Terms','Category','Category.CategoryTranslations')
        ->where('tbl_article.a_id',$id)
        ->first();
```

However the following fails with an Exception:

```
    $article = Article::with('ArticleTranslations',
        'ArticleTranslations.Terms','Category','Category.CategoryTranslations')
        ->where('tbl_article.a_id',$id)
        ->where('tbl_articleTranslation.at_languageId',$language->getKey())
        ->where('tbl_categoryTranslation.ct_languageId',$language->getKey())
        ->first();
```

... while the Exception is like this:

> (3/3) QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
>   column 'tbl_articleTranslation.at_languageId' in 'where clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `tbl_article` where `tbl_article`.`a_id` = 1 and
>   `tbl_articleTranslation`.`at_languageId` = 2 and
>   `tbl_categoryTranslation`.`ct_languageId` = 2 limit 1) in
>   Connection.php (line 664) at Connection->runQueryCallback('select *
>   from `tbl_article` where `tbl_article`.`a_id` = ? and
>   `tbl_articleTranslation`.`at_languageId` = ? and
>   `tbl_categoryTranslation`.`ct_languageId` = ? limit 1', array('1', 2,
>   2), object(Closure)) in Connection.php (line 624)

However I am sure that `tbl_articleTranslation.at_languageId` exists. Where may I be going wrong and is there a more correct way to do it?

Comment: The "where" attributes apply to the tbl_article table only and that field does not exist in there. Translations, Categories and other related models that you load with "with()" are loaded in separate queries and those where statements are not applied. What is it that you're trying to load from the database?

Comment: Ok that makes sense, understandable so far. An Article has a ArticleTranslation which has a Language. I want to load the Article only with the required Language (which has the id $language->getKey()). How would I do this best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the related records that get loaded with your Article, you need to apply constraints to the relations.

In order to load **all articles** but include only translations for given language, do the following:

```
$article = Article::with(
  'ArticleTranslations' => function($query) use ($language) {
    $query->where('at_languageId', $language->getKey());
  },       
  'ArticleTranslations.Terms',
  'Category',
  'Category.CategoryTranslations' => function($query) use ($language) {
    $query->where('ct_languageId', $language->getKey());
  }
)->findOrFail(id);
```